# What melts faster at room temperature, frozen salt water or frozen fresh water?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-transition, physical-chemistry

Suppose you freeze 2 ice cubes in the same freezer at -6F.  One cube is pure water, the other is a saltwater cube.  Take both cubes out of the freezer at the same time and put them into a room at say 72F (room temperature). Which one will melt faster?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does salt water melt faster or slower than pure water?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/530376/)